Alpinejs xtext performance in magento project
I’m new to working on a Magento project with Hyvä Theme and Alpine.js.
On the product page, I have a JSON containing product models that I’ll receive from Typesense. My plan is to use PHP for the initial rendering (prioritizing SEO) and Alpine.js to manage HTML updates dynamically when selecting a different model using a selector.
I’m considering using x-text to bind the JavaScript object to the necessary html tags, and updating the variable holding this object when the selector changes. Could this approach cause any issues with SEO or performance? Would it be better to manage the updates using a function that modifies the necessary HTML elements with .innerHTML instead of x-text?
Here’s a small example of what I’m trying to do:
> $products = json_decode(json with models);
>  $defaultProduct = $products[0];
>  <div x-data="initProductPage()">
>          <select id="model-selector" @change="updateModel($event)" >
>           <option value="Model1">Model1</option>
>           <option value="Model2">Model2</option>
>          </select>
>         <h1 id="example" class="flex" x-text="currentProduct?.name"><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__($defaultProduct['name']))?></h1>
>  </div>
>  <script>
function initProductPage() {
products: <?= json_encode($products) ?>,
currentProduct: <?= json_encode($defaultProduct) ?>,
updateModel(event) {
this.currentProduct = this.products.find(product => product.model === event.target.value);
other option
document.getElementById("example").innerText = this.currentProduct.name;
>                 }
>       }
>  </script>

My page won’t have just one h1 with the product name—this was a simplified example I used for the question, not the actual code.
My concern is whether using PHP to populate data on the initial render, combined with x-text, could cause any problem. This is because when Alpine.js initializes, it replaces the text content of the HTML element with the value from the bound variable. In the example I gave, it would work like this:
1.  The  is initially populated with defaultProduct['name'] using PHP.
2.  Alpine.js initializes and replaces the  content with currentProduct.name.
3.  When the model selector changes, currentProduct is updated, and the  value changes accordingly to the new currentProduct.name.
Advantages:
•   Data is seamlessly tied to the currentProduct object, so there’s no need to manually update the HTML tags.
Disadvantage:
•   On the first render, Alpine.js replaces the  text with currentProduct.name, even though PHP has already set the same value. I’m not sure if this double replacement could cause any issues with SEO.
The alternative approach using x-ref and innerText would work like this:
1.  The  is initially populated with defaultProduct['name'] using PHP.
2.  Alpine.js initializes, but it doesn’t modify the  until the selector changes.
3.  When the model selector changes, I use something like document.getElementById("example").innerText = this.currentProduct.name to update the .
I’d love to hear your thoughts on whether the x-text approach has any SEO implications or if the x-ref method is a better choice in this scenario.
Thank you!

I don't see the performance issue with the native x-text option. Perhaps if there are many products, the JSON would bloat the HTML and may be long to traverse in this.products.find(). Some AJAX pagination would then be relevant.
As for SEO with $defaultProduct, I have to admit that I am not convinced. You are populating the HTML with only one product name ; which IMO, is quite poor for SEO. I think a better approach would be to:

load a selection of products in PHP, populate JSON-LD with the main data (name, description, image, link, ...)

Forget about populating h1 with defaultProduct['name']

Put an Alpine x-href on the JSON-LD script tag (if ever possible ; never tested)

Parse the x-ref content in the Alpine component to retrieve the products and populate the component's data with it.


You also may be interested in using Zermatt (https://www.zermatt.dev) to decouple Alpine JS from the template and implement cleaner JS logic ; perhaps with 3rd party libraries.

Hi, thank you for your response!
I’ve edited the question with more details to make my concern clearer.
